# AWS Batch is not getting triggered from Eventbridge scheduler/rule

Tags: aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

I have created a batch job to run a simple python program from ECR Docker and able to submit the job and it is getting executed successfully.

I am trying to trigger the same batch job from eventbridge scheduler/rule. I have given all the required details and tried with admin role for execution from eventbridge but no luck.

I see the same job execution count from the Batch dashboard. I have created rule to capture event logs as one target and able to see the event logs but not the Batch job logs or at least run count in the dashboard.

I have followed the AWS documentation and as well as blogs..

Please suggest me where i am missing or is there any additional set up has to be done. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Can you please disable retries on the target and deliver any errors directly to an SQS queue to inspect invocation errors (assuming the rule gets triggered)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.. I have routed the errors to SQS and see the below error, but i have created the share identifier in the scheduling policy and included while creating the job.                                               
          Share identifier   Weight factor
           aiopsshare         1                                                                                                                         
Name                    Type           Value 
ERROR_CODE        String          ClientException
ERROR_MESSAGE  String           shareIdentifier is required.

Comment: Here is my payload : { "JobDefinition": "core-test-def", "JobName": "core-test-job2", "JobQueue": "aiops-job-queue-2"}

Comment: It is working fine after adding the share identifier in the payload. thanks and can close it.